# MERN - No errors but still not creating user in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, mern

Here's the repo https://github.com/QexleLLC/Otlic

I started up the frontend `npm start`, and the backend `nodemon server` everything seemed to be going successful. Went localhost:3000/signing, added signup details, clicked signup and nothing happened. Not even in the console, checked my MongoDB database and no new users seem to have been created. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove the word 'api' from the routes on the file authRoutes.js. The reason is that in index.js, you set up the authRoutes on /api in the first place:

```
otlic.use("/api", authRoutes);
```

this means that the authRoutes are already on /api.

In authRoutes.js, you need to chop off the /api from the beginning of the routes. Where you currently have

```
router.post("/api/signup"
```

you should just have

```
router.post("/signup")
```

Try that and see if it works.

Comment: Is your database hosted by Atlas?

Comment: That is just for the frontend, it's unrelated to the mongodb connection which is the underlying problem. Did you change your code in server/index.js to console log the result of your connection to mongodb? This will spit out either a success message or an error. 

Another question - are you using a replica set for mongoDB?

Comment: A replica set is a set of multiple instances of mongo db's but I assume you're not using them. I would look at the error you're getting when you try connecting to mongoDB. If you can put that code here it would be more helpful for solving your issue